Some PostgreSQL tables are not accessible from application using Npgsql, C#/ASP.NET
Background
I am currently writing the server-side application for an online turn-based in-browser game. I have set up a PostgreSQL database with a variety of tables within the default public schema but the two that matter for the purpose of this question are users and game_requests. These were created with the commands below respectively and populated with test data.
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users
(
    user_id integer NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    username varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    email varchar(256) NOT NULL,
    password varchar(64) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id),
    CONSTRAINT "user_id_UNIQUE" UNIQUE (user_id),
    CONSTRAINT "username_UNIQUE" UNIQUE (username),
    CONSTRAINT "email_UNIQUE" UNIQUE (email)
);

ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS users
    OWNER to postgres;
    
GRANT ALL ON TABLE users TO postgres;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS game_requests
(
    game_request_id integer NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    player_id integer NOT NULL,
    date_created varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    time_control integer NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (game_request_id),
    CONSTRAINT "game_request_id_UNIQUE" UNIQUE (game_request_id),
    CONSTRAINT "game_requests.player_id" FOREIGN KEY (player_id)
        REFERENCES public.users (user_id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE SET NULL
        NOT VALID,
    CONSTRAINT "game_requests.time_control" FOREIGN KEY (time_control)
        REFERENCES public.time_controls (time_control_id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        NOT VALID
);

ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS game_requests
    OWNER to postgres;
    
GRANT ALL ON TABLE game_requests TO postgres;

Additionally, I have a C#/ASP.NET Core API that will handle the backend validation and logic for the game. I am using the Npgsql library to connect to the database and execute queries.

The Problem
I am unfortunately, only able to access some tables via my Npgsql connection. Specifically, I can access the users table but not the game_requests table.
When I execute the below code:
NpgsqlConnection connection = new NpgsqlConnection(GlobalConstants.ConnectionString);
string command = "SELECT * FROM users;";
NpgsqlDataReader reader = await new NpgsqlCommand(command, connection).ExecuteReaderAsync();
Console.WriteLine(reader.HasRows);

I correctly get true printed to the console. However, when I change it to select from the game_requests table, i.e.
NpgsqlConnection connection = new NpgsqlConnection(GlobalConstants.ConnectionString);
string command = "SELECT * FROM game_requests;";
NpgsqlDataReader reader = await new NpgsqlCommand(command, connection).ExecuteReaderAsync();
Console.WriteLine(reader.HasRows);

An exception is called on the ExecuteReaderAsync line with the message 42P01: relation "game_requests" does not exist.
It is worth noting that this is not the case within PGAdmin. That is, I can retrieve rows from the game_requests table from within that application so the table definitely does exist.

What I've Tried
I found an answer on a similar question on Stack Overflow that mentioned using the below code to ensure the table exists within the public schema.
SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name='game_requests';

In PGAdmin, it successfully returns a row with information about the table with the table_schema field listed as 'public'. From within my application, however, there aren't any rows - signifying that the table doesn't seem to exist (or, I guess, isn't accessible).
In the case of the users table, there isn't such discrepancy. I get a populated response within my application just as within PGAdmin.
I should also note, both applications are accessing the database with the same login credentials so there shouldn't be any access issues due to that.
I feel like I'm missing something really simple. Why is one of my tables working while the other isn't? I would appreciate any advice you can provide on the matter.
Thanking you in advance.

EDIT 29/03/2024:
I neglected the fact that the game_requests table had a constraint that depended on the existence of a time_controls table. The code for this can be found below.
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS time_controls
(
    time_control_id integer NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    "time" integer NOT NULL,
    time_unit varchar(16) NOT NULL,
    increment integer NOT NULL,
    increment_unit varchar(16) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (time_control_id),
    CONSTRAINT "time_control_id_UNIQUE" UNIQUE (time_control_id)
);

ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS time_controls
    OWNER to postgres;
    
GRANT ALL ON TABLE time_controls TO postgres;


Not reproduced, but: first time i was unable to create game_requests, cause it references public.time_controls table, which is not specified in your code sample. So, created it without constraint. Both tables are accessed and returns data.

I appreciate your response @Ryan. Apologies, I forgot that constraint was there. I'll update the question shortly with the time_controls table added. It's good to know you were able to get both tables working. At least I now know they aren't the problem. Do you think it could it be a server/database configuration issue?

What role (user) does the app use to connect? Check the Grants for the game_requests table. A couple side notes:1. Your unique constraints on the PK columns are redundant. When a column (or multiple columns) define the PK that/those column(s) automatically become unique not null.  2. Use of generated by default is unusual. It allows specification of the column value on insert and to change on update. This is not wrong but must be used very carefully, normal usage is generated always.  Which prohibits both the above.
